# How to declare the values of arrays in a switch statement in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, switch-statement

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to figure out how I declare the values of arrays in switch statements. I'm used to using PHP and Javascript often and I can't figure out how I'd have to do this in C#. This is what I have right now:

```
string winkel = winkelDropdown.SelectedValue;
ArrayList products = new ArrayList();
output.Text = "Bij de " + winkel + " moet ik dit meenemen:<br />";
switch (winkel)
{        
    case "Albert Heijn":
        products.Add("Boter");
        products.Add("Kaas");
        products.Add("Eieren");
        break;
    case "Jumbo":
        products.Add("Spek");
        products.Add("Lamsvlees");
        products.Add("Huiswijn");
        break;
    case "Plus":
        products.Add("Spaghetti");
        products.Add("Pastasaus");
        products.Add("Kaasbroodje");
        break;
    case "Emté":
        products.Add("Jupiler Krat");
        products.Add("Barbeque kolen");
        products.Add("Frisdrank");
        break;
}
foreach (string product in products)
{
    output.Text += product + "<br />";
}
```

Is there a way in C# to make my switch statement shorter? For example something like this:

```
string[] productArray = string[3];
switch (winkel)
{        
    case "Albert Heijn":
        productArray = ["Boter", "Kaas", "Eieren"];
        break;
    case "Jumbo":
        productArray = ["Spek", "Lamsvlees", "Huiswijn"];
        break;
    case "Plus":
        productArray = ["Spaghetti", "Pastasaus", "Kaasbroodje"];
        break;
    case "Emté":
        productArray = ["Jupiler Krat", "Barbeque kolen", "Frisdrank"];
        break;
}
```

Comment: Your second sample should actually compile if you change first line into string[] productArray = new string[3] . Also ArrayList is rather old-fashioned.

Comment: I would **strongly** suggest using `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`

Comment: @pijemcolu and a bunch of other changes ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I would use `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`.

Second, if you want to add a range of items, use `AddRange()` and pass in a new string array:

```
string winkel = winkelDropdown.SelectedValue;
List<string> products = new List<string>();
switch (winkel)
{        
    case "Albert Heijn":
        products.AddRange(new [] { "Boter", "Kaas", "Eieren" });
        break;
    case "Jumbo":
        products.AddRange(new [] { "Spek", "Lamsvlees", "Huiswijn" });
        break;
    //etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AddRange`for this:

```
string winkel = winkelDropdown.SelectedValue;
ArrayList products = new ArrayList();
output.Text = "Bij de " + winkel + " moet ik dit meenemen:<br />";
switch (winkel)
{        
    case "Albert Heijn":
        products.AddRange(new string[] {"Boter", "Kaas", "Eieren" });
        break;
        // ...
}
```

Comment: probably because of the use of `ArrayList`

Comment: I think its because you've missed a good opportunity to teach a new C# developer about the benefits of `List<T>` over `ArrayList`

Comment: Ok, I understand that.

Answer (score 0):

you almost got it :)

```
        string[] productArray;
        switch (winkel)
        {
            case "Albert Heijn":
                productArray = new[] {"Boter", "Kaas", "Eieren"};
                break;
            case "Jumbo":
                productArray = new[] { "Spek", "Lamsvlees", "Huiswijn"};
                break;
            case "Plus":
                productArray = new[] { "Spaghetti", "Pastasaus", "Kaasbroodje"};
                break;
            case "Emté":
                productArray = new[] {"Jupiler Krat", "Barbeque kolen", "Frisdrank"};
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Per your posted code, you can't bypass the `switch` statement but as already answered you can use `AddRange()` method to add list of `string` at once. Finally, it's awful using `ArrayList` instead use `List<string>` like

```
List<string> products = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Dictionary

```
var winkelToProducts = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
// init winkel to its' products
var products = winkelToProducts[winkel];
```